# Texworks preview does not update when attached to Smartboard

Tags: texworks

We've installed Texworks and Miktex at our college. It is on a teacher machine in a classroom which passes whatever is on its screen to the classroom SmartBoard.

If I create a source file and compile, the preview is fine. But when I add some extra writing and compile again, the pdf does not update in the previewer. If I close the previewer and compile again, it does update.

If I do the same thing on a machine that the students use (not connected to the Smartboard), the update compiles and shows up just fine in the previewer.

Finally, if I return the teacher machine (connected to the Smartboard) and use TexStudio, this problem does not occur.

Has anyone else experienced this with Texworks on a PC (Windows 10) heading to a Smartboard?

Comment: Normally SmartBoards allow you to write on the board and then capture the content. My guess would be that updating the PDF might lose this content. On the other hand, are you using Adobe Reader? acroread on Windows cannot update an open PDF as the file is locked. You need a saner operating system or a different PDF viewer in that case.

Comment: @cfr I use the Texworks editor for the source code and I use the Texworks previewer to display the PDF. Just Texworks.

Comment: Maybe the file is still locked. I know Adobe locks and Sumatra, I believe, does not.